# How to block invalid requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, statistics, http-status-code-404

I have a website, which was infected 4 years ago (!) by virus, which created many threads and fake users in ASP.NET Community like : /forum/members/Better-Flower-Delivery-Your-Flower-Delivery-c-uj.aspx .

This site is redesigned 2 years ago, ASP.NET Community is removed at all, but right now there are many requests are being went to my web-site (300 such fake requests per 2 hours)!

Of course requestor (robot) gets HTTP 404, but sends and sends such requests. Any ability to block these requests at all? Why do I want to do it?

1. I use Azure. So, I pay about each incoming data / CPU time to processing request.
2. these requests add litter to statistic, so, I should check what is it.

Comment: If think this would be better suited for ServerFault since this issue should be addressed on the service configuration level rather than on asp.net programming level.

Comment: hm, how to do it on Azure?

Comment: That's what I think the pros over at SF will be able to tell you. Just flag your post for mod attention and ask to migrate it there. But of course you can wait a little and see if it gets answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

1. OnBeginRequest event, send to user a fake page with only one html form that contains some special generated number or string for this user inside hidden field and after page is loaded automatically send this form back to your server by js.
2. On your server, check this generated number, and if it's valid for this user, generate cookie that informs your system, that this is true user and has a browser.
3. So if user has your generated cookie with your generated pass, you are allow your server to process this request, if not, reject it.

This method allows you to control which request should be processed by your system, 'cause usually robots don't process responses.

Best regards, Dima.

Comment: Won't this cause a large increase in loads by adding in the extra server hops? Also wouldn't this tax OP more since `So, I pay about each incoming data / CPU time to processing request.` ?

Comment: You will do this only one time for user for some period of time (period that your generated cookie is valid). After you add cookie to client, this cookie will be passed with each request (this cookie will contain only your unique number or string, so it'll be very small size cookie), so you just check, that cookie exists, i'm fine, this request can be processed. And, of course, you can test this solution and try to optimize as best as you can. But it just the way you can look at, but I hope that you can find more elegant solution for your problem.

Comment: I was just a passer by and curious- thank you for the explanation; I hope it helps OP too.